# How can I download an information page of Stack Overflow tags?

Tags: support, tags

I am unable to download the information page of Stack Overflow tags. Is there a way to download information pages in the same way as we can download excerpts of Stack Overflow tags, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55889331/how-to-download-all-tags-in-the-posts-table)?

Comment: How exactly can you "download excerpts of stack overflow tags"? Please explain how you do this (probably some external tool) and someone might be able to help. Generally speaking, there is no existing way to "download" neither of those.

Comment: By using the query mention in following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55889331/how-to-download-all-tags-in-the-posts-table

Comment: The query in there show no excerpt, just pairs of tags and their count. I really have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you referring to the tag info? What does this have to do with HTML and why do you consider this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the information in the main part of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info, that's the tag wiki, and those can be downloaded with the help of the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). They're posts, like questions and answers, so queries like [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1581731/tag-wikis) will fetch the HTML for you. The Markdown would be available from the PostHistory table. To get the excerpts (I don't see how that can be done on the Q&A page you linked to) you should join on `ExcerptPostId` rather than `WikiPostId`.

Comment: Well the question is so unclear that I'm really not sure that's what OP is looking for. :/

Comment: Yeah I hope they come back and clarify ... this is my best guess.